# How do I query multiple properties of events within Mixpanels' JQL?

Tags: mixpanel

`function main (){ return Events({ from_date: "2023-04-06", to_date: "2023-05-26", event_selectors: [{event: "FeedExited"}, {event: "GameExited"}, {event: "DiscoveryExited"}] }) .filter(function(event){return event.properties.UserName && event.properties.InviteCode}) .groupBy(["properties.UserName", "properties.InviteCode"], mixpanel.reducer.count()); }`

Tried the code above, but it just returns a sum of count of the three events.